# Regular expression matching (if not ... return not...)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's the solution to leetcode problem: Regular expression matching.

I'm looking at this recursive approach but don't quite understand the logic of the first case. "if not pattern: return not text" what does that mean?

```
def isMatch(self, text, pattern):
    if not pattern:
        return not text

    first_match = bool(text) and pattern[0] in {text[0], '.'}

    if len(pattern) >= 2 and pattern[1] == '*':
        return (self.isMatch(text, pattern[2:]) or
                first_match and self.isMatch(text[1:], pattern))
    else:
        return first_match and self.isMatch(text[1:], pattern[1:])
```

I only want someone explain the first logic. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`not pattern` evaluates to True if the pattern is empty, False otherwise.

`not text` evaluates to True if the text is empty, False otherwise.

`if not pattern: return not text` therefore means: If the pattern is empty, return True if the text is empty, too. Otherwise return False.

A confusion matrix:

```
|Pattern \ Text  |  empty   | non-empty |
|---------------------------------------|
|empty           |  True    |  False    |
|---------------------------------------|
|non-empty       | (rest of the code)   |
|---------------------------------------|
```

Comment: it evaluates to true, even if pattern/text is None, not just empty

Comment: Yes, if it's "falsy". I was assuming that both are of the type `str`.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Nice explanation.

Answer (score 0):

when you put something into "if" statement, is should be evaluated to boolean.

```
if not pattern
```

means pattern should be evaluated to false for this "not pattern" to be "true". 
Then, return "not text", which again, evaluated to boolean

Some examples:

```
str = "bla"
>> not str
>> false 

str = ""
>> not str
>> true
```

The pattern "if":

```
pattern = "some_pattern"
if not pattern:
    print("no pattern")  # nothing be printed

pattern = ""
if not pattern:
    print("no pattern")
>> no pattern
```